# Control a Windows download manager using an Android device

Tags: applications, windows, downloading, download-manager

Can anyone please tell me if there's currently a way to use my Android device to get my Windows PC to download a file?

For example, maybe I could use the Android "Share" functionality (with a Pushbullet-like app) to send a URL to a download manager app on a Windows PC, which would then proceed to download the file.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Chrome Remote Desktop or Microsoft RD Client apps? And look at [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21693/execute-windows-run-command-or-some-windows-batch-process-from-android?rq=1) but in the comments its mentioned its dangerous advice.

Comment: Take a look at the [uTorrent Web Client](https://remote.utorrent.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [PushBullet](http://www.pushbullet.com). If you configure it so your desktop PushBullet client automatically opens all links you send to it, and you send the specific download URL, it should begin downloading it automatically, assuming you have your browser set to download to a specific location every time.